# Splitting a word into all possible 'subwords' - All possible combinations

Tags: python

I am trying to split a word into subwords - all possible permutations.

```
Input: Bang
Output: [['B','ang'], ['Ba','ng'], ['Ban','g'], ['B','a','ng'], ['B','an','g'], ['Ba','n','g'], ['B','a','n','g']]
```

I hope I covered all possbile ways to arrange 'Bang'. I thought long about it but could not find a way.

```
list(permutations('Bang', 3))
```

Permutations method does not return the entire word. I can split into 2 words but unable to split a word into 3 or more(for a bigger word).

Splitting into 2 words can be done using the below code which was suggested by one of the members.

```
[ [word[:i],word[i:]] for i in range(1,len(word))]
```

Comment: If you think of this in an abstract way, there are three locations where you can split the string which are independent of each other. So you can start by creating all possible lists of where the string should be split, e. g. `[True, False, False]` for `['B','ang']`. Then go from there with loops.

Comment: Please post your current code, including your best attempt at multiple splits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here ya go..

```
def combos(s):
  if not s:
    return
  yield (s,)
  for i in range(1, len(s)):
    for c in combos(s[i:]):
      yield (s[:i],) + c

for c in combos('Bang'):
  print c
```

Output:

```
('Bang',)
('B', 'ang')
('B', 'a', 'ng')
('B', 'a', 'n', 'g')
('B', 'an', 'g')
('Ba', 'ng')
('Ba', 'n', 'g')
('Ban', 'g')
```

Comment: The solution looks pretty elegant. I will try to understand how it is working.

Comment: Thanks - yeah play around! It's a nice problem to explore how recursion works.