# Splitting a word in all possible "Subwords"-All possible combinations W/O imports

Tags: haskell, recursion, haskell-platform

I am trying to get all the possible combinations of a word in the following manner WITHOUT using any imports:

For example...

```
    Input: Bang

    Output: [['B','ang'], ['Ba','ng'], ['Ban','g'], ['B','a','ng'], ['B','an','g'], ['Ba','n','g'], ['B','a','n','g']]
```

This problem has been bothering me for some time and i can't seem to figure out an algorithm to do this..

The code below is what i've done but this gives all the possible combinations of a string but not in the manner that i need.

I tried to implement this python code in haskell but i wasn't able to accomplish it. It basically is the same problem, but you don't have loops in haskell.

[Splitting a word into all possible 'subwords' - All possible combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242777/splitting-a-word-into-all-possible-subwords-all-possible-combinations)

The output of the code below is...

["sun","su","s","un","u","n"]

and not

[["s","un"],["s","u","n"],["su","n"]]

```
    -----------------------------------------------------


    substring :: String -> [String]
    substring [] = []
    substring xs = subs xs ++ substring (tail xs)
            where
               subs xs = foldl step [] xs
               step [] a = [[a]]
               step acc a = (head acc ++ [a]) : acc

    ---------------EXAMPLES OF EXPECTED RESULTS BELOW----------------------------------
    Input: Bang
    Output: [['B','ang'], ['Ba','ng'], ['Ban','g'], ['B','a','ng'], ['B','an','g'], ['Ba','n','g'], ['B','a','n','g']]

    Input: Sun
    Output: [["s","un"],["s","u","n"],["su","n"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is here to help. Say we have a non-empty list `x : xs`. We want to know `subString (x : xs)`. We apply our solution recursively to `xs`, so `subString xs` is a list of all solutions for `xs`. However we still have that single `x`. There are exactly two ways to bring back `x` in the solution for `x : xs` which covers for the entire solution set of `subString (x : xs)`:

- Bring `x` back *without* attaching it to its neighbor. If we have `x : xs = "Bang"` then `x` will be `'B'` and `xs` will be `"ang"` and `subString "ang"` will be `[["ang"],["an","g"],["a","ng"],["a","n","g"]]`. This is done by `[[x] : u | u <- subString xs]`. Here `u` is a list of Strings, for example `["a","ng"]`. As `x` is a character we must turn it to a String, this is done by `[x]`, attaching it to the head of the list goes by `[x] : u`, so `["B","a","ng"]`. The list comprehension will do it for all elements in `subString xs`.
- Bring `x` back attaching it to its neighbors. An arbitrary solution of `subString xs` will look like `u : us`. We want to attach `x` to the first element of `u : us` which is `u`. So `x : u`. For example `u : us = ["a","n","g"]` so `u` will be `"a"` and `us` will be `["n","g"]`. Attaching `'B'` to `"a"` is done by `'B' : "a"` and will give `"Ba"`. We have to put `"Ba` back in the list so `(x : u) : us`. The list comp[rehension looks like `[(x : u) : us | (u : us) <- subString xs]`.

We are still left with the case of a String of a single character. We write `[x]` for that where `x` is the single character. So `subString [x]` will be `[[[x]]]`.

We have to join the solutions together so

```
subString :: String -> [[String]]
subString   [x]    = [[[x]]]
subString (x : xs) = [(x : u) : us | (u : us) <- subString xs] ++ [[x] : u | u <- subString xs]
```

Example

```
*Main> subString "Bang"
[["Bang"],["Ban","g"],["Ba","ng"],["Ba","n","g"],["B","ang"],["B","an","g"],["B","a","ng"],["B","a","n","g"]]
```

Comment: Note that `subString' ""` will crash your entire program with a non-exhaustive patterns error.

Comment: @JosephSible True but easy to fix if he wants.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Elmex80s could you furtherly elaborate how the code works?I am having problems understanding it because i am new to haskell. I am assuming that it is something like the answer below given by JosephSible but im having troubles understanding its logic.Thanks again in advance!

Comment: here it is for you

Answer (score 2):

Note that the type signature of your attempt is wrong. You want all of the combinations of subword splits, which is a list of list of strings, but your type is just a list of list of strings.

This will work:

```
onHead :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
onHead _ [] = []
onHead f (x:xs) = f x:xs

combos :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
combos [] = [[]]
combos [x] = [[[x]]]
combos (x:xs) = [([x]:), onHead (x:)] <*> combos xs
```

`onHead` should be self-explanatory: perform the given function on the head of a list. `combos` recurses as follows: the subwords of a string are the subwords of its tail, with two possibilities for each: either the head is its own subword, or it's tacked onto the beginning of the first subword.

---

Update: Here's another (IMO cleaner) approach:

```
combos :: Foldable t => t a -> [[[a]]]
combos = foldr (concatMap . go) [[]]
  where go x l = ([x]:l):case l of
          [] -> []
          h:t -> [(x:h):t]
```

It's using the same technique as above, just with a cleaner implementation.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm but i accepted the 1st answer just for the sake of being the 1st.Thanks alot though really!

Comment: @rempakos You can give +1 to answers if you think it is worth it, even if you do not accept it as *the* answer.

Comment: @Elmex80s You need 15 rep to upvote, which rempakos doesn't have yet.

Comment: I tried upvoting but it didn't let me because i don't have the rep, but ill visit back and upvote if i reach that number!Thanks again!